# Is it possible to use facebook auth thru mobile application?

Tags: facebook, mobile

I am working on a website application that features possibility to log in using facebook. I am using Facebook Javascript SDK and it works fine.

However, when users are accessing the site from mobile phone (chrome/safari etc.) They are not usually logged into facebook on their browser, but they almost always have the facebook droid/iOS app installed and they are authenticated there.

Is there any way to make use of the above fact and verify their facebook identity thru the fact that they have the FB app installed. This would be much better user experience than to bother them with FB login pop ups.

Thanks for your help!
Regards

Answer (score 0):

No, you can´t use the SSO (Single Sign On) feature in the browser, you have to implement authorization on your own.